# Can I reference an existing variable when defining a new variable in Neoload

Tags: variables, neoload

I am defining some new variables in NeoLoad as in this screenshot:

[image]

I will be defining at least 10 variables like this, so the question is if it is possible to reference an existing variable in the host field? Imagine it like ${db_host} but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. but if you use javascript, you can manipulate the variables easily.
Example :
var ENV = context.variableManager.getValue("ENV");
var IDPART_REQ1 = context.variableManager.getValue(ENV + "-JDD-REQ1.IDPART");

Comment: please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the latest version of NeoLoad.

Comment: please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This option is not possible with neoload, but you can insert a JavaScript element in your test to do that